# Inventory Current Balance Report

Tags: inventory-management

Im new to SQL and I am trying to create a report that will show each item and it's current balance at every location. How do I create sql code that will show me the balance for that item at that location. Now these items can be set up at more than one location with different balance. I want to see what the balance is for that item at that location. Example.

Example:

Site ABC- item 1234 balance of 3
Site BBC- item 1234 balance of 2..

Need to so show that site with that item and the balance at that site location.

I am using Microsoft SQL.. and I have 3 tables joined..  I included the curbal in that report but the curbal is showing the same for that item in the different site locations. I need to show what that curbal is for that particular site it is located in. Just not sure how to right said function to do that.

```
SELECT INVENTORY.SITEID, INVENTORY.lOCATION, INVENTORY.ITEMNUM,       ITEM.DESCRIPTION,INVTRANS.CURBAL,INVENTORY.LM_PMMS_AUP ,INVENTORY.ORDERUNIT
FROM ((INVENTORY
INNER JOIN ITEM ON INVENTORY.ITEMNUM= ITEM.ITEMNUM)
INNER JOIN INVTRANS ON ITEM.ITEMNUM=INVTRANS.ITEMNUM);
```